# PN Sequence Generation using matlab

Tags: matlab, pseudocode

I am trying to generate a pn sequence using five shift registers.  The shift register  should be composed out of 10 states, giving us a period  of 1023 bits. I was trying hard to get it done, but I am completely confused as how to generate 1023 bits using 5 shift registers. I need to submit it by tomorrow and I am feeling really tense. Can someone please help me with this matlab code.

P.S. I am not allowed to use MATLAB's built-in functions to generate the sequence.

Comment: What functions are you supposed to use then if you cannot use the built-in functions?

Comment: I am just not allowed to use the pn-sequence generator that is s built-in function in MATLAB. Any other way is fine

Comment: I have real trouble understanding your question. How do you get 10 states with 5 registers, all other numbers in your question would match 10 registers.

Comment: Even I have the same doubt. Can you do it with 10 registers ? I am still working on it, but I guess I am stuck